# Tokenizing an arithmetic expression?

Tags: c++, stl

Say I have:

```
3.14 + 3 * (7.7/9.8^32.9  )
```

I need to tokenize this input string:

```
3.14
+
3
*
(
7.7
/
9.8
^
32.9
)
```

Is there a convenient way to do this with a stringstream or something else from STL or should I look at the input 1 char at a time and do it myself?

Comment: Using `std::regex` maybe?

Comment: See if this helps: http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/strings/split/

This might be a bit too broad for a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: When you say tokenize, in your particular case, are you trying to capture the mathematical operators as well as the numbers?  You need to better define your requirements!

Comment: @trumpetlicks It seems pretty well defined to me. There's an example in the question, and it indicates that the operators should be picked out as well.

Comment: I posted just the exact answer (using regex) to this in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725000/c11-regex-to-tokenize-mathematical-expression/56204256#56204256

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you would use `Flex/Bison` to generate a simple [lexer](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/bison/bison_5.html#SEC22) and optionally [parser](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/bison/bison_5.html#SEC27). Or if you are after `C++` compiler only solution - `Boost.Spirit` ([example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/repository/example/qi/calc1_sr.cpp)). No pure `STL` solution exists, I believe, which you would like.

I favor Flex/Bison approach, so your tokenizer written in Flex would be:

```
%{

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

%}


%option prefix="Calc"
%option noyywrap
%option c++

ws      [ \t]+

dig     [0-9]
num1    [-+]?{dig}+\.?([eE][-+]?{dig}+)?
num2    [-+]?{dig}*\.{dig}+([eE][-+]?{dig}+)?
number  {num1}|{num2}

%%

{ws} /* skip */
{number} std::cout << "=> number " << YYText() << '\n';

"+"|"-"|"*"|"/"|"^" std::cout << "=> operator " << YYText() << '\n';

"("|")" std::cout << "=> parenthesis " << YYText() << '\n';

. std::cout << "=> unknown " << YYText() << '\n';

%%

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    std::unique_ptr<FlexLexer> lexer(new CalcFlexLexer);
    while(lexer->yylex());
    return 0;
}
```

And compilation command line:

```
$ flex calc.l
$ g++-4.7 -std=c++11 -o calc lex.Calc.cc
$ calc
1 + (2e4^3)
=> number 1
=> operator +
=> parenthesis (
=> number 2e4
=> operator ^
=> number 3
=> parenthesis )
```

Comment: No, any pure STL solution would require you to effectively tokenize it yourself.  Though you can do each step as a series of iterators, and then iterate over the tokens, which would be fascinating.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you mean by 'convenient'. You can do it **easily** with a `stringstream`, but I don't know if that's what you're looking for:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

struct token{
      char c;
      float f;
      bool number;

      token():number(false),c(0){};
};

vector<token> split(string input)
{
   stringstream parser(input);
   vector<token> output;
   while(parser)
   {
      token t;
      if(isalnum(parser.peek()))
         parser >> t.f;
      else
         parser >> t.c;
      t.number = (t.c==0); 
      output.push_back(t);
   }
   output.pop_back();
   return output;
}

int main()
{
    string input = "3.14 + 3 * (7.7/9.8^32.9  )";
    vector<token> tokens = split(input);
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<tokens.size();i++)
    {
       if(tokens[i].number) cout << "number: " << tokens[i].f << endl;
       else cout << "sign: " << tokens[i].c << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that while this method is simple, it only handles `float` numbers and single character tokens.  That's not a problem, but it is a limitation to be aware of.

Comment: There's no problem in extending the method to use a `string` and a `double` instead. There's just no reason to in this example.