# C++11 regex to tokenize Mathematical Expression

Tags: regex, c++11

I have the following code to tokenize a string of the format: (1+2)/((8))-(100*34):

I'd like to throw an error to the user if they use an operator or character that isn't part of my regex.
e.g if user enters 3^4 or x-6

Is there a way to negate my regex, search for it and if it is true throw the error?

Can the regex expression be improved?

```
  //Using c++11 regex to tokenize input string
  //[0-9]+ = 1 or many digits
  //Or [\\-\\+\\\\\(\\)\\/\\*] = "-" or "+" or "/" or "*" or "(" or ")"
  std::regex e ( "[0-9]+|[\\-\\+\\\\\(\\)\\/\\*]");
  std::sregex_iterator rend;
  std::sregex_iterator a( infixExpression.begin(), infixExpression.end(), e );

  queue<string> infixQueue;
  while (a!=rend) {
      infixQueue.push(a->str());
      ++a;
  }
  return infixQueue;
```

-Thanks

Comment: Regular expressions are not very good with nested structures, like nested parentheses.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg True, but they're great at *tokenizing* because that doesn't involve nesting.

Comment: The tokenizing does work, I just wanted to not bother tokenizing if it contains operators I can't handle.

Because that means if a user types 3+5^6 => I get '3' '+' '5' '6'

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: To be clear, std::regex (since it is an ECMA compliant flavor) is unable to deal with nested structures, but the boost regex library has the features to do it and I would not be surprised that it is very fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a search on the string using the search expression `[^0-9()+\-*/]` defined as C++ string as `"[^0-9()+\\-*/]"` which finds any character which is NOT a digit, a round bracket, a plus or minus sign (in real hyphen), an asterisk or a slash.

The search with this regular expression search string should not return anything otherwise the string contains a not supported character like `^` or `x`.

`[`...`]` is a positive character class which means find a character being one of the characters in the square brackets.

`[^`...`]` is a negative character class which means find a character NOT being one of the characters in the square brackets.

The only characters which must be escaped within square brackets to be interpreted as literal character are `]`, `\` and `-` whereby `-` must not be escaped if being first or last character in the list of characters within the square brackets. But it is nevertheless better to escape `-` always within square brackets as this makes it easier for the regular expression engine / function to detect that the hyphen character should be interpreted as literal character and not with meaning "FROM x to z".

Of course this expression does not check for missing closing round brackets. But formula parsers do often not require that there is always a closing parenthesis for every opening parenthesis in comparison to a compiler or script interpreter simply because not needed to calculate the value based on entered formula.

Comment: Thanks, works!

My fault was trying to negate the regex I initially was using which had [0-9]+

But checking for [0-9] makes more sense when validating.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is given already but perhaps someone might need this

```
[0-9]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+|[\\-\\+\\\\\(\\)\\/\\*]
```

This regex separates floats, integers and arithmetic operators

Heres the trick: 
[0-9]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+ -> if its a digit and has a point, then grab the digits with the point and the digits that follows it, if not, just grab the digits.

Sorry if my answer isn't clear, i just learned regex and found this solution by my own by just trial and errors.

Heres the code (it takes a mathematical expression and split all digits and operators into a vector)

*NOTE:* I don't know if it accepts whitespaces, meaning that the mathematical expression that i worked with had no whitespaces. Example: 4+2*(3+1) and would separate everything nicely, but i havent tried with whitespaces.

```
/* Separate every int or float or operator into a single string using regular expression and store it in untokenize vector */

    string infix; //The string to be parse (the arithmetic operation if you will)
    vector<string> untokenize;
    std::regex words_regex("[0-9]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+|[\\-\\+\\\\\(\\)\\/\\*]"); 
    auto words_begin = std::sregex_iterator(infix.begin(), infix.end(), words_regex);
    auto words_end = std::sregex_iterator();

    for (std::sregex_iterator i = words_begin; i != words_end; ++i) {
        cout << (*i).str() << endl;
        untokenize.push_back((*i).str());
    }
```

Output:

```
(<br/>
1<br/>
+<br/>
2<br/>
)<br/>
/<br/>
(<br/>
(<br/>
8<br/>
)<br/>
)<br/>
-<br/>
(<br/>
100<br/>
*<br/>
34<br/>
)<br/>
```